# While loop prints message a ton of times

Tags: python-3.x

My code asks the user to input a number, if the number is an integer and it's less than 20 it finish, if not it should print "error, try again" and let's us try again, but instead of that it just freaks out and prints the message without an end

```
good1 = False
while not good1:
    storage = input("A number")
    try:
        int(storage)
        good1 = True
        good2 = False
        while not good2:
            if int(storage) > 20:
                print("Error, try again.")
            else:
                print("--")
    except ValueError:
        print("Error, try again.")
```

Comment: Please ... DEBUG your program. You never switch `good2` from `False` to any other vaue so if will never leave the loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
good_number = False

while not good_number:
    storage = input("A number")
    try:
        if int(storage) > 20:
            print("Error, try again.")
        else:
            print("--")
            good_number = True
    except ValueError:
        print("Error, try again.")
```

Answer (score 1):

You never changed value of `good2` hence it is always true and keeps on printing.

Try breaking out of the inner loop. Also, pay attention, you have set `good1` set to `True`, so it is good now even if it is greater than 20, you need to set it `False` if it is more than 20 to make the program ask again to enter new number. The code should look like this

```
good1 = False
while not good1:
    storage = input("A number")
    try:
        int(storage)
        good1 = True
        good2 = False
        while not good2:
            if int(storage) > 20:
                print("Error, try again.")
                good1 = False
            else:
                print("--")
                good2 = True;
            break
        if good2:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("Error, try again.")
```

Comment: I changed it, but now I can't try again to enter the number, the code just finish

Comment: Although the above method is not the best algorithm to solve the problem in hand. Only a single boolean flag `good` will suffice as given by @Zachary Blackwood, but here I wanted to explain you how to code the algorithm you have thought of, not how to solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have

```
while not good2:
```

This runs forever. Because you're basically saying while true, check if int is >= 20. If it is, post error else post "--". Then the if statements keeps running because good2 was never changed to false (or rather, true because NOT good2)